# Additional weight when taking a bike with Air Brunei

Tags: air-travel, luggage, bicycles

I am flying to Melbourne with Air Brunei from London. I have heard that they increase your base allowance (30kg) when you travel with a bike (by approx 8-15kg).

I can't though find any documentation on their website about this and only have anecdotal evidence (from blogs and an instance from some friends).

> Some airlines like royal brunei and Malaysia will include a bicycle in
>   your 30 kilo check in weight, acually, when you tell them you have
>   bicycle i think they throw 15kilo in for free….But it depends on the
>   airline..and as I’ve said in another comment, people should contact
>   it, read the oversized luggage policy

Does anyone know the bike luggage allowances for Air Brunei (for a standard ticket) and whether these need to be booked in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the [23kg for checked baggage](https://www.flyroyalbrunei.com/en/brunei/information/essential-travel-information/), Royal Brunei Airlines gives a 12 kg waiver for bicycles:

> [Sports equipment may be carried as part of the free baggage allowance](https://www.flyroyalbrunei.com/en/brunei/information/essential-travel-information/#special-items) in accordance to the class of travel.
>
> The following equipment are eligible for a 5kg waiver:
>    - Snow and/or water skiing equipment
>    - Angling equipment
>    - Surfboards and/or other surfing equipment (NOT including windsurfing)
>    - Bowling balls
>
> While the following are eligible for a 12kg waiver:
>    - Golf equipment
>    - Bicycles
>    - Diving equipment
>
> Please note that these waivers may not be combined with other waivers. Should multiple waivers be present, only the largest would apply.

Should that be insufficient, the airlines allows for the [pre-purchase of extra baggage allowance](https://www.flyroyalbrunei.com/en/brunei/plan/seats-baggage/#pre-purchased-extra-baggage-allowance).

Comment: It is worth noting that this additional baggage does not need to be booked or confirmed in advance - for bikes at least. They simply increase your weight limit at checkin when they see you have a bike